# Number when using "one of those who..."

Tags: verb-agreement

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> 1. He is one of those who prefer studying over traveling.
> 2. He is one of those who prefers studying over traveling.

Should the verb after the "one of..." clause agree with the subject in number? Or should it just be plural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**prefer** refers to **those guys,** and should be in the plural - Those guys prefer.

Those guys prefer studying to travelling.  He is one of them.  He is one of those guys who prefer studying to travelling.

Answer (score 3):

You confused yourself by the way you phrased the question.  The verb "prefer" is not "after" a "clause", it is part of the object of a prepositional phrase. The main verb of the sentence is "is", rendered properly as singular.  And  "those who prefer studying over travelling" is a phrase that acts as a plural noun. So Centaurus is absolutely right; the verb "prefer" must be plural.